# How add tab menu item with external link to article node content

Tags: routes

I want to add an extra tab menu item to article node type.

I mean a new menu item beside view, edit and other tabs only in article node.

but this tab menu item has **external link** to another site and it's target is **_blank** (to open destination in new window)

what is your solution for my issue?

Comment: I believe with hook_menu and title callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create custom module  Replace mymdulename with your module name.
2. implement hook menu to add "Menu local task" which let your menu
   item to show along with view, edit ..
3. page call back to add the
   redirect rule, in below example I am redirecting to google.com, you
   can add a check according to node and add redirection rule.
4. access callback ensures this menu tabs gets attached to nodes for article
   content type.

> /**  * Implements hook_menu().  */
>
> ```
> function mymodulename_menu() {
>   $items = array();
>
>   $items['node/%node/movies'] = array(
>     'title' => 'Movies',
>     'page callback' => 'mymodulename_redirect',
>     'page arguments' => array('node', 1),
>     'access callback' => 'mymodulename_content_type_check',
>     'access arguments' => array(1),
>     'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
>     'weight' => 100,
>   );
>
>   return $items;
> }
>
> /**
> * Access callback
> */
> function mymodulename_content_type_check($node) {
>   if ($node->type != 'article') {
>     return FALSE;
>   }
>   return TRUE;
> }
>
> function mymodulename_redirect($node) {
>   dpm($node);
>   $url = "http://www.google.com";
>   drupal_goto($url, array('external' => TRUE));
> }
> ```

**Update**

to open the external link in new tab use jquery to add '_blank' attribute
in your custom

```
jQuery('.tabs a').attr("target","_blank");
```

Remember to pick unique classes instead of ".tab" to avoid having this behaviour to all tabs.